# Convert Timestamp to MM-DD-YY using Cast Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

`SELECT` statement looks like:

```
    SELECT Co.info, FROM_UNIXTIME(co.date,'%m-%d-%y'), P.fname, P.lname
FROM Course C, Comment Co, Professor P
WHERE C.cID = Co.cID
AND C.cID = ?
AND P.pID = Co.pID;
```

Its datatype in the DB is Timestamp, was looking to use possibly CAST to transform the output.

How can I get it to output it in MM-DD-YY order, currently it displays: `2011-04-17 20:35:22`

**Datatype in DB:** [image: tbl]

**PHP Code including date field:**

```
<?php
  if ($sth2->rowCount()) {
    while($row = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      echo "<p>{$row['date']} <img src='img/ProfessorTag.png' 
        alt='Course Rating about {$row['fname']} {$row['lname']}'/> 
        {$row['fname']} {$row['lname']}<br />
        <img class='left' style='margin:5px;' src='img/courseComment.png'/>
        {$row['info']}</p>";
      }
    }
    else 
    {
      echo "<h3 style='color:red;'> No comments found, please 
        <a href='index.php'>find a professor</a> .</h3></div>";
    }
```

Comment: @user7, edited the layout of your code, please layout the code using spaces (with indent =2) in such a way that everything fits inside the screen with no scrolling needed.

Comment: @user7, oh and tabs are broken in SO they break up your layout.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(co.date, '%m-%d-%y')
FROM    co
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FROM_UNIXTIME()`

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(col,'%m-%d-%y');
```

Comment: I'm not sure if your column is timestamp, but this works fine `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1303496242,'%m-%d-%y');`

Comment: This does not work, it gives me the error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '%'" I've included screenshot above that shows the column type

Comment: That's a PHP error, and you have a PHP string concatenation problem. It's not a MySql error.

Comment: Pentium - its giving me that error from the code you gave me :) , please see my updated code above, any reason why it doesnt like the '%'

Comment: The SQL code is missing from the PHP code. Please include that too.

Comment: @user700070, I can confirm that the code Pentium10 gave you works. Maybe you have single quotes on your string in php?

Comment: Guys - the SQL is being included in the file that contains code with $sth, etc...

Comment: Please understood for once, that the problem is on line where you write the query, not how you display. You have a single quote string concatenation problem when you build the query string.

Comment: in the Php file, it is using `{$row['date']}` and in the sql, it states: SELECT Co.info, FROM_UNIXTIME(Co.date,'%m-%d-%y'), P.fname, P.lname
    FROM Course C, Comment Co, Professor P
    WHERE C.cID = Co.cID
    AND C.cID = ?
    AND P.pID = Co.pID;

Comment: Do you begin the string with single apostrophe? Write it like this `\'%m-%d-%y\'`